# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined-IONIC2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm trying  to  implement InAppBrowser in IONIC2.

Fetched Browser Plugin

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

My .TS code  to  open browser

```
browser(url:string)
{
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
           open(url, "_blank", "location=true");
        });
```

}

my HTML  code

```
 <button (click)="browser('https://www.google.com')" >Open Browser</button>
```

while  trying to  execute

the  following  error coming

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined

ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined
    at HomePage.browser (http://10.44.71.150:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:180:22)
    at DebugAppView._View_HomePage0._handle_click_27_0 (HomePage.template.js:500:28)
    at http://10.44.71.150:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:26022:24
    at http://10.44.71.150:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:34969:36
    at http://10.44.71.150:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:35039:93
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://10.44.71.150:8100/build/js/zone.js:323:29)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://10.44.71.150:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:30600:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://10.44.71.150:8100/build/js/zone.js:322:35)
    at Zone.runGuarded (http://10.44.71.150:8100/build/js/zone.js:230:48)
    at NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded (http://10.44.71.150:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:30633:78)
```

Is  there  something  I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you initializing the `platform` variable in the `constructor` of your .ts?

Make sure you are importing it first, like this:

```
import {Platform, ...} from 'ionic-angular';
```

And then in the constructor:

```
constructor(private platform: Platform, ...) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue as well.
The tutorial I was using instructed me to add this code to the class declaration:

```
  static get parameters() {
        return [[Platform]];
    }
```

Removing this code prevented the error, and InAppBrowser worked smoothly afterwards.

I realize that this response is late, but I hope it may help someone else who runs into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had to mark the variables in the constructor as private for them to work properly for myself.

```
  browser(private url:string, private platform: Platform)
  {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       open(url, "_blank", "location=true");
    });
```